# Fake email generation using factory.LazyAttribute

Tags: email, faker

I am trying to generate fake email ID's for the purpose of research.  I employ LazyAttribute towards this end. I want the email ID to correspond to the first and the last names of the person (generated using Faker).  The function I wrote is below.

I am unable to get the expected output. If the name of the person is John Snow, I see the following as the output:

John    Snow    <factory.declarations.LazyAttribute object at ......

Can I expect some help to fix my code?  Thanks!

```
def faker_categorical(num=1, seed=None):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    fake.seed_instance(seed)
    output = []
    for x in range(num):
      gender = np.random.choice(["M", "F"], p=[0.5, 0.5])
      output.append(
        {
            "First name": fake.first_name(), 
            "Last name": fake.last_name(),
            "E-mail": factory.LazyAttribute(lambda obj: "%s@example.com" % obj.first_name),  
        })
    return output
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating email address using first name and last name in Faker python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356668/generating-email-address-using-first-name-and-last-name-in-faker-python)

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I have accepted your answer.